# Specify hardware to use for hotpsot

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

Good day all,

Is there a way to specify which hardware to use when creating a hotspot in Windows 10?

I have an onboard PCI Wi-Fi card and a USB Wi-Fi dongle. I'm using the PCI card for internet connectivity and I want to use the dongle to boost the wifi in my apartment like an extender.

I know software like Connectify can specify hardware but I would like to know if there is a setting in Windows 10 I can use

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused.  Having used this feature in a device with multiple wireless adapters (in order to use the Hotspot feature) whichever adapter is used to create the Hotspot is the adapter that is used.  There isn't a need for a tool, you already have the ability, to select which adapter is used.

Comment: I'm not at home right now but I'll check when I get there. However, I am pretty sure that there is only an option to change the name and password of the hotspot and which connection to "hotspot-ify". Are you saying that by selecting the PCI card's connection as the shared connection, windows will automatically use the dongle to create the hotspot? I doubt this because some adapters have the ability to activate the Microsoft Virtual Adapter whilst simultaneously having a wifi connection